# Vuetify Color Variant Attribute Inside Component Tag

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add color variant to the Navigation Drawer component as a HTML attribute. My custom primary color works, but I want to add `primary-darken3` color variant. Navigation Drawer component looks like this:

```
<v-navigation-drawer absolute permanent color="primary" class="sidebar-container">
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I'm able to add `primary-darken3` color variant to the component by adding custom css style:

```
.sidebar-container {
    background-color: var(--v-primary-darken3) !important;
}
```

I wonder if is there a way to use this color variant by passing it somehow to the component's color attribute or as some other attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class `darken-3` to the navigation drawer component :

```html
<v-navigation-drawer absolute permanent color="primary" class="darken-3">
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

you could do this with any component uses `color` prop

Comment: Thank you, it works. I'll accept answer after 3 minutes timeout.